# How to set up poll questions beforehand?

Tags: jitsi

In Jitsi Meet, I want to set up poll questions beforehand, that I can then choose to send out at any point in time. E.g.

> Poll Q1: “What is 1+1?” Possible responses: “0”, “1”, “2”, “3”, “4”
>
> Poll Q2: “What is 2×2?” Possible responses: “0”, “1”, “2”, “3”, “4”

Right now (unless I’m missing something), it seems that I have to type in real time each of the above poll questions.

Or, alternatively, I can have all the poll questions entered beforehand, but then all of these poll questions will be shown immediately to anyone who enters the meeting.

I want to instead show each poll Q to the participants at a time of my choosing. So, some option to hide each poll Q until I decide to unhide it would also work well. But right now I can’t seem to find any such option.

(I'm using Jitsi Meet and would prefer using that and not set up my own server.)